# which element index has triggered the input event?

Tags: java, jquery

I have got a selector that selects multiple inputs with the given ID. I have got on input event that triggers when inputs changes for one of the inputs. I would like to check which input index position has triggered the input event. I guess they will be stacked or in my case they will be a list of Ids stored into array.

```
var getsIds $("#nameInput");

$(getsIds).on('input', function()){
//which event index from getsIds has triggered the input event 
}
```

where `#nameInput` is a list of inputs generated in the view and they all share the same id:

```
foreach(var items in Model){
<input type="text" id="nameInput" value="@items.name" >
}
```

bottom line is I would like to set validation on the input that triggered the event keeping them with the same Ids. How can I check which input triggered the event when they all share the same Ids ?

Comment: You can use `$(this)` inside the function to get which input triggered the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs should be unique- only one element should have an ID on a page.  When you use `$('#nameInput')` to select them all, it'll only select the first since jQuery anticipates only one element with that ID.

You can add a class name instead:

```
<input type="text" id="nameInput1" class='nameInput' value="1" >
<input type="text" id="nameInput2" class='nameInput' value="2" >
<input type="text" id="nameInput3" class='nameInput' value="3" >
<input type="text" id="nameInput4" class='nameInput' value="4" >
<input type="text" id="nameInput5" class='nameInput' value="5" >
```

Then you can select them all, and use either the ID or the index within the parent (assuming they're all in the same parent element) to identify which was changed. `this` in the listener will refer to the HTML element just changed and `$(this)` will change that element into a jQuery object to manipulate.

```
var getsIds = $(".nameInput");
$(getsIds).on('input', function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
  console.log($(this).index());
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yLdqhv8a/